# VLC - much worse video quality than other players (horizontal stripes)

Tags: video, snap, vlc

Last few weeks I have noticed much worse video quality in VLC than in other video players (compared to Ubuntu 20.04 preinstalled Video player and mpv media player).
It is latest stable version from Ubuntu store (also tried beta latest beta version, but the problem is the same).
Most noticable are horizontal stripes:

Screenshots:

VLC: https://postimg.cc/VJGNRV2j

Video player: https://postimg.cc/cKPLq8xC

What could be the problem? Settings in VLC are default, no changes in system in last times... After new install of vlc I have also deleted .config folder. Horizontal stripes are still visible.

Thank you for help!

---

---

UPDATE:
I still have the same problem with stripes. For few days the solution from below (to install via terminal, not a snap version) worked, but now it is still the same.
What else could be the problem?

Tnank you for help!

Comment: What happens  when you install the apt versioin with `sudo apt install vlc` instead of the vlc from the snap store?

Comment: Well, that solved the problem. But that is the catch? Isn't the program the same? Thank you!

Comment: Snap is a new technology, and still has a lot of issues.

Comment: Did you have a graphics driver update or a kernel update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may be related to the `snap` version of VLC, and the `apt` version won't have this issue.

Enter the command to install the `apt` version of VLC.

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

And enter the following command to remove the snap version

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

I would suggest not to use snaps or flatpaks for widely available software unless you require the very latest version for some reason. `snap` is still quite a new technology. They consume more storage space, more bandwidth, and are slow on first startup compared to the the same software installed from `apt`.

Of course, snaps/flatpak are a great way to get software that is otherwise not available/hard to install, but for common software, they are really not required.

Comment: I just updated the question - problem with stripes returned last week. I have reinstalled VLC as you suggested (installed via Terminal sudo apt-get install vlc, not a snap version), but now it is still the same. Much worse quality than other players...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but in my case, I didn't install it using snap.

What I did to fix it was to go to Tools > Preferences and change the output from automatic to X11 video output (XCB)