# Stripey videos on all media players Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, video, vlc

Hi I did a clean install of Ubuntu for the first time yesterday.
When I tried to watch a video with vlc the quality is very "stripey".

I found this question [VLC - much worse video quality than other players (horizontal stripes)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305176/vlc-much-worse-video-quality-than-other-players-horizontal-stripes)
The problems are similar.

But that solution didn't work for me.
I also tried the mpv media player with the same results.

Youtube plays in good quality.

EDIT: added a screenschot with the artefact clearly visible
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t76bw.jpg)

Comment: Is [this](https://linuxhint.com/install_multimedia_codecs_ubuntu/) resource of any help?

Comment: No it doesn't do the trick. Videos still play stripey.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that what you are seeing is called tearing.
This happens in video games that render at a high framerate and don’t turn on v-sync.
It is better to turn on v-sync, however, the game rendering will be limited to your monitors refresh rate (which is not necessarily a bad thing).

Another thing is that maybe your Ubuntu is using the Compositor in order to do various animation effects with OpenGL. If v-sync is not enabled, then you will have tearing since the Compositor, just like a game, would be rendering at a high frame rate like 200 FPS while your monitor might be only 60 Hz.

In my case, I use Kubuntu 20.10. (This uses the KDE interface. I don’t know about the GNOME interface of Ubuntu)
Press on
-Start → Applications → Settings → System Settings

-The System Settings window opens

-On the left side, click on Display and Monitor

-In the next list, click on Compositor (It is the second one in the list)

-On the right side, Tearing prevention (“vsync”) , set it to Automatic.

-At the bottom right, click the Apply button

Comment: Well it not like screen tearing. If you look at the post i linked you can see it's almost like watching it through shutters, it's horizontally pixelated almost.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was disabling the hardware acceleration.
In VLC, that can be done at Preferences > Input/Codecs > Hardware-accelerated decoding > Disable.